# POSTing to Sinatra with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby, post, sinatra, slim-lang

I have the following routes

main.rb

```
get '/' do
    slim :initial
end

post '/' do
    params.inspect
end
```

initial.slim

```
input id="coolBtn" type='button' value='POST Me'

javascript:
    $("#coolBtn").click(function() {
        $.post("/", { name: "John", age: 27 });
    });
```

Here

```
post '/' do
   params.inspect
end
```

After I clicked a button, I want to be redirected and see my passed JS object (or similar to it). But the code above didn't do it. When the button is clicked nothing happens. No errors, no messages... I've perused some related topics here but nothing helps me so far. Is it some misconception I'm missing here? How to do POST requests from within JavaScript to Sinatra App?

Answer (score 2):

Open up your page inspector (Firebug or the like) and you should see a POST request. The issue is that $.post is asynchronous (an AJAX request), and will not redirect the page.

Instead use a form element with a submit button to make redirecting POST requests.

Comment: I've added <form action="/" method="post" id="formID"> with <input type="submit" value="Btn">. jQuery now is: $("#formID").submit(function(...)). Yes, I see my POST in Firebug BUT after I clicked the button and got redirected to "/", in Ruby, params.inspect returns an empty hash {}. Why? I thought I would get my ajax data.

Comment: are there parameters in your post request? check the console again. You may need a field in the form to get parameters

Comment: It seems like a workaround: in <form> I added <input type="text" name="task" id="textID">, in jquery submit I added: $("#textID").attr("value", '{"name": "John", "age": "27" }'). From post '/' I fetch this data with: JSON.parse(params[:task]).inspect.


It looks, for me, like an awful workaround. In addition, after clicking the button, for a fraction of a second text input becomes flooded with json data (apparently because of $().attr()).

Thanks for the suggestion, but maybe there is something else that could probably help me?

Comment: @Semuserable AJcodez is right, basically, you're misusing the AJAX request. If you want to POST and be redirected, then don't use AJAX - why would you, HTTP's natural direction is to do what you want. Just add the redirect at the end of the `post` route and remove the AJAX call, just allow the HTTP to do its stuff. If, however, you wish to stay on a page and POST things, use AJAX, it's perfect for it.